# Navigation ul tag binding error in ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJs. I'm trying to make a eCommerce website and have created the navigation. But I'm facing a specific problem.

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot my ul tag is repeating, which shouldn't be the scenario.

I m sharing the code below as what I have implemented.

topNavigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SubMenu from './subMenu';



class Navigation extends Component {

  state = {
    mainCategory: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3030/topCategory')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.express);
        this.setState({
          mainCategory: res.data.express.catalogGroupView
        })
      })
  }



  render() {

    const { mainCategory } = this.state;
    return mainCategory.map(navList => {
      return (

        <ul className="header">
          <li key={navList.uniqueID}>
            <a className="dropbtn ">{navList.name} </a>
            <ul className="dropdown-content">
              <SubMenu below={navList.catalogGroupView} />
            </ul>


          </li>
        </ul>

      )

    })

  }


}

export default Navigation;
```

subMenu.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SubListMenu from './subListMenu';


class SubMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        const { below } = this.props;
        return below.map(sub => {

            return (

                <React.Fragment>

                    <li key={sub.uniqueID}>

                        <a>{sub.name}</a>

                        {
                            <ul className="sub-menu">
                                {sub.catalogGroupView !== undefined && <SubListMenu subBelow={sub.catalogGroupView} />}
                            </ul>


                        }

                    </li>

                </React.Fragment>

            )
        })

    }

}

export default SubMenu;
```

subListMenu.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class SubListMenu extends Component {

    render() {
        const { subBelow } = this.props;
        console.log(subBelow)
        return subBelow.map(subl => {

            return (


                <li key={subl.uniqueID}><a>{subl.name}</a></li>




            )
        })

    }

}

export default SubListMenu;
```

index.css

```
.header{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  list-style-type: none;

}

.header .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;    
  border: none;
  color: #111;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.header:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #00b5cc;
}


.dropdown-content {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.header:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.drop-button {
  font-size: 16px;    
  border: none;
  color: #111;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.sub-menu{
  list-style-type: none;
  display:none;
}

.dropdown-content:hover .submenu{
 background-color: red;
}
.dropdown-content li:hover .sub-menu { 

  display: block; 

}

img{ 
    width:100%;
  }
```

Whenever I see my code in console window, the ul tag becomes duplicated. I don't know where I m getting it wrong.Can somebody please guide me on this. Or give an insight how to proceed regarding the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `<ul>` elements in your map.

```
 return mainCategory.map(navList => {
      return (

        <ul className="header">
          <li key={navList.uniqueID}>
            <a className="dropbtn ">{navList.name} </a>
            <ul className="dropdown-content">
              <SubMenu below={navList.catalogGroupView} />
            </ul>


          </li>
        </ul>

      )

    })

  }
```

Wrap the map inside the `<ul>` like this:

```
<ul className="header">
    {mainCategory.map(navList => 
        (
            <li key={navList.uniqueID}>
                <a className="dropbtn ">{navList.name} </a>
                <ul className="dropdown-content">
                    <SubMenu below={navList.catalogGroupView} />
                </ul>
            </li>
        )
    })}
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: There is not need of return with arrow functions as it is implicit

Answer (score 1):

Your ul is inside `mainCategory.map` so a new ul will be produced for each mapped item.

`return <ul className="header"> {mainCategory.map(funtion)}</ul>` will produce one ul

Answer (score 1):

Because your `ul` is inside the `map`. Your render method should be like the following:

```
render() {
  const { mainCategory } = this.state;
  return (
    <ul className="header">
      {
        mainCategory.map(navList => (
          <li key={navList.uniqueID}>
            <a className="dropbtn ">{navList.name} </a>
            <ul className="dropdown-content">
            <SubMenu below={navList.catalogGroupView} />
            </ul>
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: My css is not working....It's not displaying now inline-block after making the changes. Please help

Comment: @SajjadTabreez Can you share your code on codesandbox?

Comment: Yes Surely. I will send

Comment: can you help me now

Answer (score 0):

Since you include parent list tag `<ul>` inside of the .map method, at each iteration new `<ul>` construction will be created. All you need to do is to wrap your .map method in `<ul></ul>`.